# Swift NSTimer Exception

Tags: swift, nstimer

I'm getting a weird bug with my code, when I try to assign/run a timer its throwing an exception.

```
var timer: NSTimer?
     self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "repeatData", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Here is my function

```
 private func repeatData() {
        print("test")
}
```

This throws

```
016-02-01 14:45:31.169 twu[43110:60021261] -[Test.Repeater repeatData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f848ba14e10
```

Error without :

```
2016-01-28 17:27:51.958 my_target[16476:48497867] -[Test.Repeater repeatData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd06bc1c310
2016-01-28 17:27:51.968 my_target[16476:48497867] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Test.Repeater repeatData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd06bc1c310'
```

I've tried it with and without the colon.

Comment: It's the use of the word private alright, just did a test... not sure why

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you `repeatData` is `private`. Just remove the `private` and your timer should work.

The methods being with selectors need to be accessible methods otherwise it wont find them, that's why it is crashing with the `unrecognized selector` error

Comment: This is only half right. The reason it doesn't work is due to the generated headers.

Answer (score 0):

The selector should be `"repeatData"`. The colon means that the method takes a parameter which your implementation of `repeatData` does not.

Comment: I've tried it with both and the error persist.

Comment: Print the error you get without the colon because it simply CANNOT be the same.

Comment: @Woodstock I've added the other error

Comment: Is the private function in the same swift file as the NSTimer call?

Comment: Yes @Woodstock it is